# Incorrect Totals in Power BI Table for MAPE

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm fairly new to Power BI and struggling with an issue around totals in a table.

I am trying to calculate Mean Average Percentage Error (MAPE) using the following calculation:
[ABS(Actuals - Forecast)/Actuals]

Below is my dataset:

[image: MAPE_Dataset]

The total in the 'MAPEX' Column is actually the sum of the totals in 'AbsErr' / 'Actuals' columns: (1457.27 / 2786.27 = 0.52).

What I actually need to show is the sum of the values in 'MAPEX' which totals 5.88.

The 'MAPEX' column is a Measure with the following definition:

```
MAPEX = DIVIDE([AbsErr], sum(CUBE_PeriodicData[Actuals]),0)
```

I do not need to show the correct total in the 'Total' row in the table, it can be placed elsewhere in the report as a card, I would just like to know if there is a function in DAX that I am unaware of which will total the values in the column vertically?

Comment: The granularity matters. Do you always want to add up Absolute Percentage Error of each ItemName, Year, and Month? In that case, there is a simple solution. But if, for example, you may sometimes want to add up APE of each ItemName, Year, and Quarter, the result may not be the same. It would not be possible to switch the granularity used in the calculation depending on which drill-down level is selected in the visualization...

Comment: Yes, i always want to do this. The item and year will change, but the total should always reflect the 12 monthly values for the current selected Item in the chosen year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seymour's answer looks to be good, but I'm here to add a little that **granularity** matters in this scenario.

Assuming you have a star schema like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecDWh.png), it is pretty straightforward you can define measures Total Forecast, Total Actual, Absolute Error, and Absolute Percentage Error with below formulas.

```
Total Forecast            = SUM ( Forecast[Forecast] )
Total Actual              = SUM ( Actual[Actual] )
Absolute Error            = ABS ( [Total Forecast] - [Total Actual] )
Absolute Percentage Error = DIVIDE ( [Absolute Error], [Total Actual] )
```

Here is what you will get so far.

[image: Result 1]

Here, you are asking how to calculate the sum of Absolute Percentage Errors.

By definition, Absolute Percentage Error shows the value of Absolute Error divided by Total Actual **regardless of the drill-down level**. Therefore at the grand total, it shows 0.52 which is Absolute Error (1,457.27) divided by Total Actual (2,786.27). If you want it to calculate differently in the grand total level, you need to explicitly implement this logic.

Your requirement would be stated more explicitly like below:

1. Calculate the values of **Absolute Percentage Error in the granularity of each ItemName, Year, and Month**.
2. And **add them up**.

The function you will need to implement this logic is `SUMX`. Also, you may explicitly use `SUMMARIZE` to make sure you are calculating Absolute Percentage Error in the specific granularity.

```
MAPEX = SUMX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        Forecast,
        'Product'[ItemName],
        'Calendar'[Year],
        'Calendar'[Month]
    ),
    [Absolute Percentage Error]
)
```

[image: Result 2]

I have been emphasizing about the granularity so far. This is because if you are not conscious of the granularity, the result may look strange in some cases.

In the above image, MAPEX looks to be the same as Absolute Percentage Error except for the grand total. However, if you drill-down by Quarter instead of Month, you will notice it is not the same at all.

[image: Result 3]

Absolute Percentage Error is showing the quotient of Absolute Error and Total Actual at **quarterly** level, whereas MAPEX is still summing up **monthly** values of Absolute Percentage Error, even though Month is not being displayed in the table.

So, my final word is, whenever you invent a new measure like MAPEX, you always need to ask yourself if it makes sense or not for every possible granularities.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this would be to use a custom column titled MAPEX instead of a measure that does your calculation. If there is a particular reason you need to use DAX please feel free to let me know and I may be able to figure something out.

Column = ABS(([Actuals]-[Forecast])/[Actuals])

EDIT: Just in case, the way you create a new column is with this button in the view tab.

[image: Add New Column]

Alternatively, you can create the custom column from within the query editor which appears to be working for me.

[image]

Comment: Hi Josef, thanks for your reply. I have tried this but the values are not correct, i.e. January was 0.58 in 'MAPEX' and in new column = 9.33 - also the Total and at least one of the column values now shows 'infinity'.

Comment: Can I see the formula for your new column? Thanks!

Comment: I just added another screenshot which may help clear things up a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Go with this

VAR _mytable = SELECTCOLUMNS(FactTable, "MAPE", ABS(Actuals - Forecast)/Actuals))
Return
Sumx(_mytable, [MAPE])